# Printing in patterns in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am having a great trouble to remove the errors in unicode encoded corpus.
In following form

```
രണവര്‍ഗ്ഗത്തിനകത്തു=ഭരണവര്‍ഗ്ഗത്തിന്:stemഅകത്തു|:suffix
ഭസ്മമാക്കിക്കളയുകയും=ഭസ്മം:stemആക്കിക്കളയുകയും|:suffix
ഭസ്മമാക്കി=ഭസ്മം:stemആക്കി|:suffix
ഭാഗത്തുനിന്നുണ്ടാകണം=ഭാഗത്ത്:stemനിന്ന്:stemഉണ്ടാകണം|:suffix,:
ഭാഗമായ=ഭാഗം:stemആയ|:suffix
ഭാര്യമാരില്‍നിന്നും=ഭാര്യമാരില്‍:stemനിന്നും|:suffix:suffix
ഭാര്യമാരുണ്ടായിരുന്നവരില്‍നിന്നു=ഭാര്യമാര്‍:stemഉണ്ടായിരുന്നവരില്‍:stemനിന്നു|:suffix,:suffix:suffix
ഭാര്യയായി=ഭാര്യ:stemആയി|:suffix
ഭാ‌ഷ്യകര്‍ത്താവായ=ഭാ‌ഷ്യകര്‍ത്താവ്:stemആയ|:suffix:suffix
ഭിത്തികളൊക്കെ=ഭിത്തികള്‍:stemഒക്കെ|:suffix
ഭിന്നതയില്ലെന്നും=ഭിന്നത:stemഇല്ല:stemഎന്നും|:suffix,:suffix0
ഭൂപ്രഭുക്കളെന്ന്=ഭൂപ്രഭുക്കള്‍:stemഎന്ന്|:suffix0
ഭൂമിയില്‍നിന്ന്=ഭൂമിയില്‍:stemനിന്ന്|:suffix
ഭൂമിയിലുള്ള=ഭൂമിയില്‍:stemഉള്ള|:suffix
ഭൂമിയെപ്പോലൊരു=ഭൂമിയെ:stemപോലെ:stemഒരു|:suffix,:suffix0
ഭൂമുഖവീക്ഷണനായി=ഭൂമുഖവീക്ഷണന്‍:stemആയി|:suffix:suffix
ഭൂസഞ്ചാരംപോലെ=ഭൂസഞ്ചാരം:stemപോലെ|:suffix
ഭേദിക്കേണ്ടതായി=ഭേദിക്കേണ്ടതാ്:stemആയി|:suffix:suffix
ഭൗതികവാദികളാണ്=ഭൗതികവാദികള്‍:stemആണ്|:suffix0
മക്കളയച്ചു=മക്കള്‍:stemഅയച്ചു|:suffix
മക്കള്‍ക്കാണ്=മക്കള്‍ക്ക്:stemആണ്|:suffix
മഞ്ചേരിയിലേക്കാണ്=മഞ്ചേരിയിലേക്ക്:stemആണ്|:suffix:suffix
മഞ്ചേശ്വരത്താണ്=മഞ്ചേശ്വരത്ത്:stemആണ്|:suffix:suffix
മഞ്ഞുവെള്ളത്തിലാഴ്ത്തി=മഞ്ഞുവെള്ളത്തില്‍:stemആഴ്ത്തി|:suffix:suffix
മടങ്ങാണിതിന്=മടങ്ങ്:stemആണ്:stemഇതിന്|:suffix,:suffix
മടിയനായിരുന്നു=മടിയന്‍:stemആയിരുന്നു|:suffix
```

Where I need to remove two stem together  and  two suffixes together. In the case of two stems I need keep first stem and convert the second into suffix. In the case of  two suffixes like this `:suffix:suffix`, `:suffix,:suffix0` I need to keep only one suffix

```
use strict;
use warnings qw/ all FATAL /;

use List::Util 'reduce';

while ( <> ) {

    my ($word, $ss) = / \( ( /[^()]* ) \) /gx;

    my @ss = split ' ', $ss;

    my $str = reduce { sprintf 'S (%s) (%s)', $a, $b } @ss;

    printf "%s (%s)\n", $word, $str;
}
```

This is the perl code I am trying to change but that code is not sufficient to handle the complexities. Is there any way to handle the kinds of errors.

```
**Expected output**  

`ഭാര്യമാരുണ്ടായിരുന്നവരില്‍നിന്നു=ഭാര്യമാര്‍:stemഉണ്ടായിരുന്നവരില്‍:stemനിന്നു|:suffix,:suffix:suffix` to
ഭാര്യമാരുണ്ടായിരുന്നവരില്‍നിന്നു=ഭാര്യമാര്‍:stemഉണ്ടായിരുന്നവരില്‍:suffixനിന്നു|:suffix

ഭാ‌ഷ്യകര്‍ത്താവായ=ഭാ‌ഷ്യകര്‍ത്താവ്:stemആയ|:suffix:suffix to
ഭാ‌ഷ്യകര്‍ത്താവായ=ഭാ‌ഷ്യകര്‍ത്താവ്:stemആയ|:suffix
 മഞ്ചേരിയിലേക്കാണ്=മഞ്ചേരിയിലേക്ക്:stemആണ്|:suffix:suffix to
മഞ്ചേരിയിലേക്കാണ്=മഞ്ചേരിയിലേക്ക്:stemആണ്|:suffix
```

Any one interested in helping me?

Comment: @simbabque Updated the post

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: I can share whole dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

```
^([^:]+:stem[^:]+)(?::stem(?=.*?(:suffix))|)([^:]+?\|:suffix[^:]*)(?::suffix[^:]*)*$
```

**Replace with:** `\1\2\3`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- Assumes that each line will have a `suffix` string this is then pattern matched and pulled into the capture group 2
- If there is a second `stem` it is replaced with `suffix`
- Removes all but the first `suffix` entries

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/rJ9gW3/2

**Sample text**

```
ഭാര്യമാരുണ്ടായിരുന്നവരില്‍നിന്നു=ഭാര്യമാര്‍:stemഉണ്ടായിരുന്നവരില്‍:stemനിന്നു|:suffix,:suffix:suffix
ഭാ‌ഷ്യകര്‍ത്താവായ=ഭാ‌ഷ്യകര്‍ത്താവ്:stemആയ|:suffix:suffix
മഞ്ചേരിയിലേക്കാണ്=മഞ്ചേരിയിലേക്ക്:stemആണ്|:suffix:suffix
```

**Sample Matches**

```
ഭാര്യമാരുണ്ടായിരുന്നവരില്‍നിന്നു=ഭാര്യമാര്‍:stemഉണ്ടായിരുന്നവരില്‍:suffixനിന്നു|:suffix,
ഭാ‌ഷ്യകര്‍ത്താവായ=ഭാ‌ഷ്യകര്‍ത്താവ്:stemആയ|:suffix
മഞ്ചേരിയിലേക്കാണ്=മഞ്ചേരിയിലേക്ക്:stemആണ്|:suffix
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]+                    any character except: ':' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :stem                    ':stem'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]+                    any character except: ':' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :stem                    ':stem'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        :suffix                   ':suffix'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]+?                   any character except: ':' (1 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \|                       '|'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :suffix                  ':suffix'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]*                    any character except: ':' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :suffix                  ':suffix'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]*                    any character except: ':' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```